# Как сделать безопасную авторизацию с vkontakte для html5 приложения работающего через iframe?

Tags: php, javascript, vkontakte-api

**Как сделать безопасную авторизацию с vkontakte для html5 приложения работающего через iframe?**

Создал приложение, работающее через websocket. В данный момент авторизация через куки, хочу наконец начать работать с vkontakte api. Весь гайд перечитал нигде не описан простой способ индифицировать пользователя.
Мне нужно просто уникальный ключ пользователя, под которым я сохраню его настройки на сервере в xml файле. Нужно чтобы этот уникальный ключ, нельзя было прислать подменой, я думаю в ВК апи это хорошо должно быть реализовано.

На будущее тем, кто будет искать мой вопрос: клиенская сторона:

```
var auth = findGetParameter("auth_key");
if (auth) {
var id =findGetParameter("user_id");
socket.send('9'+'|'+auth+'.'+id );
}
```

функция для взятия гетов

```
function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
        var result = null,
            tmp = [];
        var items = location.search.substr(1).split("&");
        for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
            tmp = items[index].split("=");
            if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
        }
        return result;
}
```

серверная(пхп):

```
$auth_key = md5('Фашайдиприложения' . '_' . $id . '_' . 'ФашЗащитный ключ');
if($auth_key==$auth) //пропускаем создаем пользователей
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, есть такое. Про `auth_key` и способ его проверки можно подробно почитать [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/apps_init?f=3.%20auth_key). 
Он, ровно как и другие необходимые данные, передаётся при входе в приложение в качестве GET параметров.

Comment: Большое спасибо, я совсем потерялся в обилии документации вк. Как только разберусь, выберу ответ.